# Can I reorder SQL selections after the limit has been applied?

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

I'd like to see the last ten rows from our mysql database in ID order.  Naively, I'd expect to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM things ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) ORDER BY id ASC
```

but that isn't valid syntax.  What's the correct way of expressing the query I'm trying to run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got that almost right:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  ( SELECT * FROM things ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) xxx
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Note the innocent `xxx` after the subselect which you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM things ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) temp
ORDER BY id ASC
```

You need something like that because here FROM clause is executed even before the SELECT.