# How to fetch next page of database records using two fields as starting point?

Tags: sqlite, pagination

When returning database results based on two columns, how do you paginate?

It's easy enough using limit and offset, but super slow for larger datasets.

I've seen plenty of ways to do it if one column search term remains constant - you just remember the last record of the other column, and display past that for the next page, as at http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor.

But what if you're searching using two columns that will vary?

eg browsing on First Name and Last name, ordered by first name, then last:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY firstname COLLATE NOCASE ASC, lastname COLLATE NOCASE ASC LIMIT 100
```

Displays 100 rows, and the last row might be Angela Smith, so you remember this in two vars, then to display the next page...

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE firstname>="Angela" COLLATE NOCASE AND lastname>"Smith" COLLATE NOCASE ORDER BY firstname COLLATE NOCASE ASC, lastname COLLATE NOCASE ASC LIMIT 100
```

That works correctly for displaying the rest of the names when their firstname is Angela, but then, say after Angela comes Aria, only Aria's with the last name > "Smith" will be displayed.

What's the proper way to query this?

Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sorting first by firstname and then by lastname, names would be ordered like this:

```
Angela  Smith   <-- last record
Angela  Zwick
Aria    Aames
Aria    Smith
Aria    Zucker
```

For people with the same first name, the last name must come after "Smith".
But for people with a larger first name, the last name does not matter at all.

So the proper filter condition would be something like this:

```
WHERE (firstname = 'Angela' AND lastname > 'Smith')
   OR firstname > 'Angela'
```

Comment: Thank you CL. I had another solution I figured out, but yours is WAYYYY simpler and more elegant. It slotted in nicely. I'm wondering now if there's a standard way, when pagination backwards, ie making the > sign a <, to offset the results without using OFFSET? I've used OFFSET before so backwards pagination doesn't always jump back to displaying page 1, but the idea was to avoid OFFSET because of it's performance hit.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I've figured it out. I had to change my query ordering to DESC so it would select the correct rows, and then wrap it in an ASC to display it correctly - here's the wrapping part I got from this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255636/can-i-reorder-sql-selections-after-the-limit-has-been-applied